# putextra textview to spinner android

Tags: android

i want to putextra textview into spinner. in my case my spinner get data from database use `BaseAdapter`.

```
public class GetLocationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Location> item;

    public GetLocationAdapter (Activity activity, List<Location> item) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.item = item;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_location_name, null);

        TextView locationName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);

        Location data;
        data = item.get(position);
        locationName.setText(data.getNamelocation());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and my code spinner in fragment :

```
adapter = new GetLocationAdapter(getActivity(), listLocation);
        spinner_location.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this code getExtra :

```
String locationName = this.getArguments().getString("LocationName");
```

my question, how to spinner getText from `locationName` ?

Comment: where to add this location in spinner?? at last position or at first position????

Comment: first position @BapusahebShinde

Comment: Just add it to your listLocation list before creating the adapter.

Comment: @josef.adamcik how is code ?

Comment: Just create Location object and pass it to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E) If you are not able to do it you should step back and try to learn some basic java and programming.

Comment: @josef.adamcik, i want to  add text to spinner from putExtra (TextView) not from database, but from the database I was able to do it

Comment: I understand what you want.  I'm talking about java code, not about datadabase. Just create the Location object (new Location()), set name (you should know how to do that, I cannot because you haven't shown source of Location class) and add it do the list (list.add(0, location)).

Comment: @josef.adamcik, thanks bro, worked !!